# Is there an advantage in converting user provided \hfuzz values to sp?

Tags: tex-core

I was looking through the `fancyvrb` code. At a point it defines a key `hfuzz`
as follows:

```
\define@key{FV}{hfuzz}{%
  \@tempdima=#1\relax
  \edef\fv_hfuzz{\number\@tempdima sp}}} 

\fvset{hfuzz=2pt}
```

What is the reason to convert it to sp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you do

```
\fvset{1em}
```

in the preamble.

If the code just did `\def\fv_hfuzz{#1}` the value of `em` current at point of usage would be used (maybe influenced by some `\footnotesize` or similar declaration).

The code in `fancyvrb.sty`, instead, freezes the value at point of definition.

You also get an error in case of an input such as `\fvset{hfuzz=2}`.

On the other hand,

```
\edef\fv_hfuzz{\the\@tempdima}
```

would be as good.

Comment: Thanks and Merry Christmas, so no advantage in converting to `sp` units?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I see none at all: the conversion from `pt` to `sp` is completely predictable. Maybe the author likes integers better than floating point numbers.